# WPF Button with Multiple Content

Tags: wpf

I am new in WPF,I am using Button control in WPF windows application, I am displaying its content from Database,
I have its click event binded with its Name,like this

```
 <Button Content="{Binding FirstName}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="628,178,0,0" x:Name="btn1Click"/>
```

This button have different content for each user.
This is my FirstName property

```
string _fname;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _fname; }
            set { _fname= value; NotifyOfPropertyChange("FirstName"); }
        }
```

I want to get ID of the clicked user, how can I put UserID in content(with firstname)? 
or in x:Name so I can identify which user is clicked?
Or I can use some hidden field for it and how?

Comment: One option is to store the user object in `Button.Tag` property. Still, I recommend taking closer look at [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx) (and `Button.CommandParameter` property in particular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a property to commandParameter and can check where you have binded the command to the event handler. like

```
<Button Command="{Binding BtnClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />

In ViewModel of this view:

BtnClickCommand=new RelayCommand(o=>BtnClickEvent((string)o));// Cast you id to whatever data type u have.


private void BtnClickEvent(string Id)
{
    //Here you got your id and do what u want..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign DataContext property of button's parent with the user object then in the click event of a button write following code.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button item = sender as Button;
        if(item != null)
        {
            //you will get user details here by using item.DataContext property
            User clickedUser = item.DataContext  as User;
        }
    }
```

Here you will get all the details of Clicked User.

Comment: Thanks, I am using MVVM pattern,can I assign Content to User entity?